# Extract data from web site using ABAP

Tags: abap

I would like to know how it is possible to extract information from a website (http://www.bcentral.cl) using ABAP. Is it possible?

I have little experience in ABAP and I would not know where to start. After obtaining the information I must update ABAP table with those values. Here is the info I need to take out of the website.

[image: Web site]

Comment: It looks like Banco Central de Chile provides some [Web Services](https://si3.bcentral.cl/estadisticas/Principal1/web_services/index.htm).

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work like this, like you intend to do it. Parsing text from web-page directly in ABAP is possible, but cumbersome and inefficient.

Usually currency rates and other indicators are consumed via web-services/XML, that are provided by financial institutions, and Banco Central de Chile [is not an exclusion](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://si3.bcentral.cl/estadisticas/Principal1/web_services/Webservices/series.xls).

Here is [the page](https://si3.bcentral.cl/estadisticas/Principal1/web_services/index.htm) where they explain how to use their web-services, and even provides [an example](https://si3.bcentral.cl/estadisticas/Principal1/web_services/webservices/MT.pdf) (real example, Karl!) how to consume this web-service in your application.

Consuming web-service in ABAP is not as much complicated than in C#. Here is the step-by-step guide:

https://blogs.sap.com/2013/07/29/consuming-webservices-directly-from-abap/

Comment: thanks, I will review everything and tell you the final result

Comment: To cross the T's and dot the I's, you'll take the WSDL file given in [the page](https://si3.bcentral.cl/estadisticas/Principal1/web_services/index.htm) and use it when you create the proxy in ABAP to consume the web service as explained in the SAP blog post mentioned above.